# Atomically update and return in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I wanna select a row in my table, increment a value and return it and meanwhile I don't want any other concurrent processes have access to that row. How can I do in PostgreSql?

Also, I can't use a sequence because every row has it's own column that needs to be incremented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will be interested in the RETURNING clause of UPDATE. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

RETURNING takes a list of fields to return from the updated rows.

Comment: Thanks. Is this atomic? I must return distinct value per call. 
Also, can I select row by Id and do the update with one query?